# Reading content from .bin file in C Error on first fread value

Tags: c, binary, fread

i've been having some issue with my fread function.
everything reads nicely but my error checker goes off on the first value of fread and i 
have absolutely no idea to as why.

if i've rewinded back to the begining of the file, and it prints my value correctly then what failed ?

```
int main()
{
   FILE *BinFile;
   //FILE *CopyBinFile;

  // printf("Enter name of a file you wish to see\n");
   //gets(file_name);

   if ((BinFile = fopen("C:/Users/Tom/OneDrive/Desktop/out.bin","rb")) == NULL){
       printf("Error, shits broke");
       exit(1);
   }

    fseek(BinFile,0,SEEK_END); 
    SizeofFile = ftell(BinFile);

   printf("The contents of out.bin file are:\n");
   printf("the size of the file is %d \n", SizeofFile);

    //fseek(BinFile,0,SEEK_SET ); // point back to the start
    rewind(BinFile);

    if (fread(&Buffer4Can, sizeof(uint8_t) , SizeofFile ,BinFile) != 1){ //**<<<<--- this**
        printf("err \n");
    }

    for(c=0;c<SizeofFile;c++){
    printf("%02X ", Buffer4Can[c]);
    count++;
    if (count == 8){
        printf(" \n");
        count =0;
    }   
 }

   return 0;
}
```

UPDATED:
@ Thanks everyone for the help ! i really do appreciate it. was able to port it to stmIDE nicely and alot easier as it seems to be alot more streamlined in the library st provides

```
if ( f_mount(&MyFatFs, SDPath, 1)== FR_OK){
     HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12);    //

    if( f_open(&myFILE, "out.bin", FA_READ) == FR_OK ){
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13); //ORANGE
     }

    // get byte amount from file
    //f_lseek(&myFILE, 0x20);
    SizeofFile=f_size(&myFILE);
    //f_rewind(&myFILE);

    //SizeofFile=11240;
    //store data into buffer
    if (f_read(&myFILE, &Buffer4Can, SizeofFile, &byteCounter)== FR_OK){

    }
    HAL_Delay(2000);
        //toggle
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14);

        //untoggle
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12);
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13); //orng led
 }

 if(byteCounter==0){ /* error or eof */
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15); // blue LED
 }
```

Comment: `fread` returns the number of items read.  In this case, since `size` is 1, it returns `SizeofFile` bytes.  So you should be checking against this number ie. `if (fread(.....) != SizeofFile)`.

Comment: thanks @david & Domenic. why dont you guys put these as answers ?

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have posted it as an answer.  For detailed answers, though, I do post them as answers. :-)

Comment: `"just showing the first line of my file"` - no, a binary file has no concept of lines. `Buffer4Can[120000];` will be converted to a pointer on access so no `&` is required in `fread(&Buffer4Can, ...` (note: that error is masked by the fact that `fread()` takes `void*` as a parameter, and by happy mistake the address of an array and a pointer to its first element both resolve to the same address but are of vastly different types)  (fixed typo)

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   Regarding: `#include <stdint.h.>`  There is a trailing `.` after the `h`.  Suggest removing the trailing `.`

Comment: OT: regarding all the global variables:  It is  very poor programming practice to make variables global.  Especially those that would be better written as local variables inside some function.

Comment: OT: the function: `ftell()` returns a `long int`, not an `int`

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Error, shits broke");`  1) do NOT cuss.  2)  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  3)  when the error is from a c library function, should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest: `perror( "fopen failed" );` followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  The same considerations exist for: `printf("err \n");`

Comment: OT:  always check the returned values from C library functions to assure the operation was successful.  This includes the function: `fseek()`

Comment: OT: suggest this statement: `printf("The contents of out.bin file are:\n");` be moved to just before the call to `fread()`

Comment: OT: what if the file being read is longer than 120000 bytes?   Suggest using `malloc()` to allocate a buffer bug enough to hold the contents of the file rather than allocating a (perhaps) too short a buffer and have the result be a buffer overflow, resulting in undefined behavior and perhaps a Seg Fault Event/

Comment: regarding; `//gets(file_name);`  The function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the C language since (about) 2009,  Suggest using `fgets()` then removing the trailing newline via: `file_name[ strcspn( file_name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of subtle errors and then are checking the return of `fread` against an improper value. In your call to `fread`, there is no need to precede `Buffer4Can` with the `&` (*address of*) operator. `Buffer4Can` is an array, and will be converted to a pointer to the first element on access (see: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3))

When you take the address of `Buffer4Can` you change the pointer type you provide to `fread` from `uint8_t*` (without the `&`) to `uint8_t (*)[120000)` (with the `&` the type becomes a *pointer-to-array-of* `uint8_t[120000]`). Now by happy coincidence being that `Buffer4Can` is an array, both the *pointer-to* `uint8_t` and *pointer-to-array-of `uint8_t[120000]` will both resolve to the same address (but are of vastly different types).

Since they resolve to the same address and since `fread()` takes a parameter of `void*` for its first parameter, the error goes silently unnoticed. (suffice it to say if you attempted `fread (&Buffer4Can + 1, ...` things would not work out well...)

The other issue pointed out by @Domenic is your comparison of the `fread()` return. The prototype for `fread()` is:

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

Where the return value for `fread()` is:

> ```
>    On success, fread() and fwrite() return the number of items read or
>    written.  This number equals the number of bytes transferred only
>    when size is 1.
> ```

See [man 3 fread](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html)

In your case you provide `sizeof(uint8_t)` for the `size` parameter of the function meaning for the return `"This number equals the number of bytes transferred"` or `SizeofFile` in your case. Further, just like `sizeof (char)`, `sizeof (uint8_t)` is `1` so it can simply be represented as `1`.

The only other area where you are missing a validation is prior to `fread()`, you must confirm `SizeofFile <= 120000` to protect your array bounds. You can put that together with your call to `fread()` as:

```
    if (MAXB < SizeofFile ||   /* protect bounds/compare return to SizeofFile */
        fread (Buffer4Can, 1, SizeofFile, fp) != (size_t)SizeofFile) {
        fputs ("error: file exceeds buffer size, or fread failed.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** the return type for `fread()` is `size_t` so a cast of `SizeofFile` is necessary to avoid comparison between signed and unsigned values)

When using exact-width types, the macros to use for both input and output conversion are provided in `inttypes.h` (which includes `stdint.h` itself) The macro for output of a `unit8_t` value in hex-format is `PRIx8`. To output 8 2-char hex-values per-line preceded by `"0x"`, you could do:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)SizeofFile; i++) {     /* loop over bytes */
        if (i && i % 8 == 0)                        /* output 8 per-line */
            putchar ('\n');
        printf (" 0x%02" PRIx8, Buffer4Can[i]);     /* use exact width specier */
    }
    putchar ('\n');             /* tidy up with newline */
```

(**note:** the `PRIx8` macro is not within the quoted part of the *format-string*, it stands alone. If you had wanted a newline at the end, the *format-string* would be `" 0x%02" PRIx8 "\n"`)

With that you program should function as desired. Note, it takes the filename to read as the first argument to the program, or if none is provided, it will read from `stdin` by default (you can redirect a binary file on `stdin`). Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define MAXB 120000     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    uint8_t Buffer4Can[MAXB];   /* buffer to hold bytes from file */
    long SizeofFile;            /* size of file (note type long for ftell) */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "rb") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);    /* seek end */
    SizeofFile = ftell(fp);     /* get lenght */
    rewind (fp);                /* rewind to beginning */

    if (MAXB < SizeofFile ||   /* protect bounds/compare return to SizeofFile */
        fread (Buffer4Can, 1, SizeofFile, fp) != (size_t)SizeofFile) {
        fputs ("error: file exceeds buffer size, or fread failed.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)SizeofFile; i++) {     /* loop over bytes */
        if (i && i % 8 == 0)                        /* output 8 per-line */
            putchar ('\n');
        printf (" 0x%02" PRIx8, Buffer4Can[i]);     /* use exact width specier */
    }
    putchar ('\n');             /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

(**note:** all superfluous variables have been removed, and note the return type for `ftell()` is `long`, not `int`)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: oh wow appreciate the help,  althought your first comment was enough to push me in the right direction i still do appreciate the time you put into this.

Comment: Glad it helped. Wasn't sure if you had succeeded or not, so I went ahead and wrote the full example. Sometimes it helps seeing it all put together. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
if (fread(&Buffer4Can, sizeof(uint8_t), SizeofFile ,BinFile) != 1)
```

the buffer `Buffer4Can`  is an array name and referencing a 'bare' array name degraded to the address of the first byte of the array. Therefore,  prepending a `&` is an error.

There is also a problem with the parameter: `SizeofFile` as the function is expecting a parameter with type `size_t`.  Suggest:

```
if (fread(Buffer4Can, sizeof(uint8_t), (size_t)SizeofFile, BinFile ) != (size_t)SizeofFile)
```

The `fread()` function returns  the number of 'items' read.  In the current statement, the size of each item is `1`, so a successful read operation will return the third parameter, so instead of comparing the returned value to `1` should be comparing to `(size_t)SizeofFile`

From the MAN page for `fread()`

*On  success,  fread()  and  fwrite() return the number of items read or
       written.  This number equals the number of bytes transferred only  when
       size  is 1.  If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the
       return value is a short item count (or zero).*

Please pay attention to returned types and parameter types and give functions what they are expecting.